# WSO2 ESB Datamapper escaping underscore (_)

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I am using data mapper mediator to convert a JSON into SOAP.

But the endpoint service has some tags with underscore:

```
(...)
<sch:idt_solic>1</sch:idt_solic>
(...)
```

In the JSON outputSchema the same tag is:

```
(...)
"sch:idt_solic" : {
    "id" : "http://wso2jsonschema.org/x:Body/sch:Data/sch:Body/sch:Request/sch:idt_solic",
    "type" : "number"
 }
(...)
```

And in .dmc file is:

```
(...)
outputx_Envelope.x_Body.sch_Data.sch_Body.sch_Request.sch_idt_solic = inputroot.Request.idt_solic;
(...)
```

But the final result is:

```
(...)
<sch:idt>1</sch:idt>
(...)
```

Everything after the first underscore is lost in the result message, and I have a similar issue with other service that had "-" in tag names.

What can I do to avoid that error?

**UPDATE**

I found a workaround to make it work:

I edited the dmc file to the following:

```
(...)
outputx_Envelope.x_Body.sch_Data.sch_Body.sch_Request["sch:idt_solic"] = inputroot.Request.idt_solic;
(...)
```

And it worked, but I am waiting for a better solution.